# AD FS and Claims Provider Trust for an external IdP

Tags: adfs

I need to add an external IdP to our organization's AD FS as a Claims Provider Trust. The external IdP has an XML metadata published, but it contains tens and tens of different external sub-organizations identified in the XML in `<EntityDescriptor entityID="[URL of the IdP for each sub-organization]"> ... </EntityDescriptor>` tags. There is no separate metadata available behind the specific URL I would need to add.

Can I use the metadata URL to add the Claims Provider Trust and somehow specify the sub-organization in it, or do I have to extract the specific part manually and add that as an XML? I would prefer not to so the trust could be monitored by the Federation Service.

I'm running the AD FS farm with Windows Server 2012 R2 (AD FS 3.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few hits and misses later I found the answer; no.

[image: adfs]

> [...] an EntitiesDescriptor with **only one EntityDescriptor.**

Also, it was pointed out to me that this is in fact possible with Windows Server 2016 AD FS: [Microsoft Docs - Improved interoperability with SAML 2.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/improved-interoperability-with-saml-2.0)